# Installing 3rd party JS plugins via npm INSIDE foundation project creates errors

Tags: javascript, npm, zurb-foundation

I'm new to projects using NodeJS and npm. 
I'm fiddling around with foundation CLI in Foundation 6.4, and Im trying to install 3rd Party JS plugins, in this case chart.js https://www.chartjs.org/

So Ive run

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

as described in their documentation: 
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html

Since I want to use this inside my foundation project, I found it sensible to execute this command from inside the foundation project, the "root" for the whole project so to say. 
However, when doing so I get a huge list of errors during the installation:

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\postcss-selector-parser-79b1786b\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\postcss-selector-parser-79b1786b\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\postcss-selector-parser-79b1786b\CHANGELOG.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\source-map-resolve-22d3c721\test\common.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uniq-b6c0c289\test\test.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\svgo-d6999a75\plugins\_collections.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\source-map-resolve-22d3c721\test\read.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\source-map-resolve-22d3c721\test\source-map-resolve.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\unique-filename-73563e8d\coverage\__root__\index.html'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\unique-filename-73563e8d\coverage\__root__\index.js.html'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\jquery-e95abfa6\src\css\var\cssExpand.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\jquery-e95abfa6\src\css\var\getStyles.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\jquery-e95abfa6\src\css\var\isHiddenWithinTree.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\jquery-e95abfa6\src\css\var\rboxStyle.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\jquery-e95abfa6\src\css\var\rnumnonpx.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex-8ad643ab\src\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\jquery-e95abfa6\src\css\var\swap.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\jquery-e95abfa6\src\data.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-dotall-regex-1df1d1be\lib\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-dotall-regex-1df1d1be\src\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\compile\async.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-dotall-regex-1df1d1be\test\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\compile\equal.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\compile\error_classes.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\compile\formats.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\compile\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\compile\resolve.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\compile\rules.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\compile\schema_obj.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\compile\ucs2length.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex-8ad643ab\test\fixtures'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\compile\util.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\ajv-89eb8fee\lib\data.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex-8ad643ab\test\fixtures\with-unicode-flag\options.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\fs-extra-cf94d4f2\lib\fs\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-gyp-5150d3a7\gyp\tools\Xcode\README'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\handlebars-5e0aecc8\lib\handlebars\base.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\handlebars-5e0aecc8\lib'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\parse\regex.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\parse\token.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\test\fixtures\custom-functions\setter-expected.css'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\test\fixtures\custom-functions\setter.scss'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\test\fixtures\custom-functions\string-conversion-expected.css'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\test\fixtures\custom-functions\string-conversion.scss'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\jsdom-afeff42d\lib\jsdom\living\xhr'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\jsdom-afeff42d\lib'
```

Furthermore, these errors seem to vary every time Im executing the installation.

```
D:\foundationtests>npm install --save chart.js
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\fined-0dc44eaf\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\parse-filepath-dd59234a\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\parse-filepath-dd59234a\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\fined-0dc44eaf\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\is-relative-8f0e46f4\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\is-absolute-6dc5e586\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\parse-filepath-dd59234a\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\fined-0dc44eaf\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\is-relative-8f0e46f4\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\is-absolute-6dc5e586\README.md'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\is-relative-8f0e46f4\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\parse-filepath-dd59234a\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\fined-0dc44eaf\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\is-relative-8f0e46f4\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\is-absolute-6dc5e586\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\is-absolute-6dc5e586\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\gulp-cli-b31321ab\lib\versioned\^4.0.0-alpha.2\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex-8ad643ab\lib\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-dotall-regex-1df1d1be\lib\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex-8ad643ab\src\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-dotall-regex-1df1d1be\src\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\src\libsass\include\sass\base.h'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-dotall-regex-1df1d1be\test'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex-8ad643ab\test'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\src\libsass\include\sass\context.h'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\src\libsass\include\sass\functions.h'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-transform-dotall-regex-1df1d1be\test\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\@babel\plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex-8ad643ab\test\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\src\libsass\include\sass\values.h'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\src\libsass\include\sass\version.h'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\src\libsass\include\sass\version.h.in'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\src\libsass\include\sass2scss.h'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\src\libsass\INSTALL'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-e9c9e34c\src\libsass\LICENSE'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\http.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\http.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\http.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\https.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\https.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\https.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\mailto.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\mailto.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\mailto.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\urn-uuid.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\urn-uuid.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\urn-uuid.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\urn.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\urn.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\schemes\urn.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\uri.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\uri.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\uri.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\util.d.ts'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\util.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\uri-js-a59e23e7\dist\esnext\util.js.map'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\fs-extra-cf94d4f2\lib\move\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\jquery-e95abfa6\src\queue\delay.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\browser-sync-ui-18c2e4d5\public\js\app.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\base-config.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\calendar.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\constructor.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\en.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\formats.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\invalid.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\lists.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\locale.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\locales.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\ordinal.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\pre-post-format.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\prototype.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\relative.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\foundationtests\node_modules\.staging\moment-01d97eee\src\lib\locale\set.js'
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/har-validator/-/har-validator-5.1.2.tgz
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'har-validator@5.1.2' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'foundationtests'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

When Im running the command from INSIDE the nodeJS folder though, everything works fine.

```
D:\nodeJS\node-v10.16.0-win-x64>npm install --save chart.js
+ chart.js@2.8.0
added 6 packages from 8 contributors in 1.403s


   ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                                │
   │      New minor version of npm available! 6.9.0 -> 6.10.2       │
   │   Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v6.10.2   │
   │               Run npm install -g npm to update!                │
   │                                                                │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

However, no matter what I do, in the end the installation and integration doesnt seem to work. 
As described in the documentation and tutorials, I added the

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
```

to my app.js of my foundation project, but when I restart my foundation watch, I get an error:

```
[10:38:51] Error in plugin "webpack-stream"
Message:
    ./src/assets/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chart.js' in 'D:\foundationtests\src\assets\js'
resolve 'chart.js' in 'D:\foundationtests\src\assets\js'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: D:\foundationtests\package.json (relative path: ./src/assets/js)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      D:\foundationtests\src\assets\js\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\foundationtests\src\assets\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\foundationtests\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in D:\foundationtests\node_modules
        using description file: D:\foundationtests\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: D:\foundationtests\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/chart.js)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js doesn't exist
[D:\foundationtests\src\assets\js\node_modules]
[D:\foundationtests\src\assets\node_modules]
[D:\foundationtests\src\node_modules]
[D:\node_modules]
[D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js]
[D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js.wasm]
[D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js.mjs]
[D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js.js]
[D:\foundationtests\node_modules\chart.js.json]
 @ ./src/assets/js/app.js 3:0-29
 @ multi ./src/assets/js/app.js
Details:
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: true

[10:38:51] 'build' errored after 13 s
[10:38:51] 'default' errored after 13 s
[10:38:51] The following tasks did not complete: images
[10:38:51] Did you forget to signal async completion?
Error: foundation-zurb-template@1.0.0 start: `gulp`
Exit status 1
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\nodeJS\node-v10.16.0-win-x64\node_modules\foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:217:16)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\nodeJS\node-v10.16.0-win-x64\node_modules\foundation-cli\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
```

So either I am doing something wrong during in the integration part, or something is missing during the installation. But Im somehow out of ideas what else I could do to make it run...

EDIT:
I should add that I dont have admin privileges on the machine Im trying to execute the installation on. This didnt pose any problem with installing Foundation ZURB Template and the like, so I guess it shouldnt be a problem, but I just wanted to mention it for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug / issue in npm. Try `rm -rf node_modules`, try it again and check if you can upgrade npm.